# Using FullCalendar in PHP page with data from mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-6

I am currently writing a simple calendar page to show some upcoming events. The events are stored in a Mysql database and I want to display them on a FullCalendar inside a PHP page. This is my first time using javascript and I need a few pointers.

In my PHP page, I use several differnt database querys, each outputting their own results into their own array, I then use `array_merge_recersive` to combine the arrays then create a json output using `json_encode()`.

Everything works fine, the events are displayed on the calendar corretly, however, I cannot find a way to pass additional options to the calendar, for example, I would like to add week numbers, the documentation says to use `weekNumbers:true` but I dont know where this argument should be.

The code I am using to display the calendar is as follows.

```
<script>
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, 
        <?php echo json_encode($merged_results);?>
        );
        calendar.render();
      });
</script>
  <div class="container">
    <div id='calendar'></div>
  </div>
```

The output of `echo json_encode($merged_rec_array)` is as follows

```
{
   "events":[
      {
         "id":"1119",
         "title":"MONTAGE - KRAN:5005 (21LC550-18) | PROJECT:P1093 K\u00f6lden",
         "start":"2023-05-29",
         "end":"2023-06-02",
         "allDay":"true",
         "backgroundColor":"green"
      },
      {
         "id":"1131",
         "title":"MONTAGE - KRAN:2010 (21LC290-12) | PROJECT:P1095 Segerdal Kv. C",
         "start":"2023-05-29",
         "end":"2023-06-02",
         "allDay":"true",
         "backgroundColor":"green"
      },
      {
         "id":"1138",
         "title":"MONTAGE - KRAN:5011 (21LC550-20) | PROJECT:P1100 V\u00e4ster\u00e5s Sjukhus",
         "start":"2023-06-05",
         "end":"2023-06-09",
         "allDay":"true",
         "backgroundColor":"green"
      },
      {
         "id":"391",
         "title":"DEMONTAGE KRAN:5005 (21LC550-18) | PROJECT:P1029 Stugan 5 - Stadshagen",
         "start":"2023-05-03",
         "end":"2023-05-07",
         "allDay":"true",
         "backgroundColor":"#d9534f"
      },
      {
         "id":"1000",
         "title":"DEMONTAGE KRAN:2005 (LC2070) | PROJECT:P1067 Kv. 8 - Jakobsberg",
         "start":"2023-05-09",
         "end":"2023-05-13",
         "allDay":"true",
         "backgroundColor":"#d9534f"
      },
      {
         "id":"1117",
         "title":"DEMONTAGE KRAN:2003 (LC2074) | PROJECT:P1071 Luthagen Strand",
         "start":"2023-06-07",
         "end":"2023-06-11",
         "allDay":"true",
         "backgroundColor":"#d9534f"
      }
   ]
}
```

I have read the documentation multiple times and spent hours searching the web, but unfortuatly I cant find a working solution.

I would like to refine my code so that I can pass the additional options to FullCalendar and have it display them as well as all my events.

The version of FullCalendar I am using is `FullCalendar Standard Bundle v6.1.6`
The version of PHP I am using is `PHP 7.4`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `I would like to add week numbers, the documentation says to use weekNumbers:true but I dont know where this argument should be`...it should be part of the options object. e.g. `{ "weekNumbers": true, "events": [ ... ] }`

Comment: I'd strongly recommend getting PHP to output _only_ the event array, and putting the rest of the config in JS. e.g. make it so you can write something like `var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, { "weekNumbers": true, "events": <?php echo json_encode($merged_results);?> });`

Comment: Even better than that: don't inject the event JSON directly into the calendar JS code. That gives you an inflexible, static list of events. And when your calendar has been there a while, and your database has 1000s of events in it going back over time, it will start to get slow, and it will be pointless because most users will probably never view most of the historical events. Instead, use a dynamic event feed as per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed , so fullCalendar can dynamically fetch only the events it actually needs to display, based on the calendar's current date range.

Comment: P.S. There are loads of demos on the fullCalendar site which (sometimes incidentally and sometimes deliberately) show you how/where to set the various options. There's even one specifically for weekNumbers - go to https://fullcalendar.io/docs/week-numbers, click on the demo, then click on the "Edit in Codepen" button, and the source code of the demo appears, showing you exactly how the option is used.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Is this a PHP problem (where you have any problem generating the proper markup), or a JS problem?

Comment: @ADyson Thank you very much for the quick responses. `var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, { "weekNumbers": true, "events": <?php echo json_encode($merged_results);?> });` worked perfectly. Now I have it working, I will look into the `dynamic event feed` option.

Answer (score 1):

The comment posted by @DYson solved my problem.

```
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, { "weekNumbers": true, "events": <?php echo json_encode($merged_results);?> });
```

I will look into using the 'dynamic event feed' as advised.